# How to fill a listview with data from sqlite table in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a table named "Userstable" with some columns.

How to fill this table into a list and get another action when click at any list entry?

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend. Always try searching for some tutorials before bringing it to stack. Here's a few tuts I found that should help you:

http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html

Comment: thank you so much, I tried more than 20 article befor, but no one met my requirement, I'll see your links now

thank you :)